# Preventing Duplicate List<T> Entries

Tags: c#, list, collections, duplicates

I expect I'll be able to make a work around but I can't for the life of me understand why this code is not functioning correctly and allowing duplicate entries to be added to the List.

The `if` statement condition is never met, even when I drag identical files in from the same location. I don't understand why the "Contains" method isn't matching them up.

[image]

```
public class Form1:Form {
    private List<FileInfo> dragDropFiles = new List<FileInfo>();

    private void Form1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e) {
        try {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop)) {
                string[] files =
                    (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);

                OutputDragDrop(files);
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }

    private void Form1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e) {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        else
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
    }

    private void OutputDragDrop(string[] files) {
        try {
            foreach (string file in files) {
                FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);

                if (dragDropFiles.Contains(fileInfo)) {
                    dragDropFiles.Remove(fileInfo);
                }
                dragDropFiles.Add(fileInfo);
            }
            PopulateContextMenu();
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

I thought I had found another method in which to achieve this using "Distinct"

However, it appears `checkedDragDropFiles` & `dragDropFiles` have the same amount of entries, including duplicates, except when `dragDropFiles` is displayed in a `ListBox` it doesn't show them. Why does it do this?

I need to prevent any duplicated list entries, as I would be programmatically creating a menu based off of the list data.

```
private void OutputDragDrop(string[] files)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);

            //if (dragDropFiles.Contains(fileInfo))
            //{
            //    dragDropFiles.Remove(fileInfo);
            //}
            dragDropFiles.Add(fileInfo);
        }

        List<FileInfo> checkedDragDropFiles = dragDropFiles.Distinct().ToList();

        debugList.DataSource = checkedDragDropFiles;
        debugList2.DataSource = dragDropFiles;
        //PopulateContextMenu();
    }
    catch { }
}
```

Comment: what makes `FileInfo`s the same, perhaps you should implement a `IEqualityComparer<FileInfo>` to pass to `Distinct`

Comment: Just a note: If `Contains` returns _true_, why remove and add? Do a negative check and only add if the list doesn't _not_ contain the value.

Comment: Oded: Good point, that is kinda a wasted action.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`List<T>` does indeed allow duplicates.

In the case of `FileInfo`, the `Contains` method will be checking whether the references are the same, but as you are fetching a completely *new* set of `FileInfo`, the references are different.

You need to use the overload of `Contains` that takes an `IEqualityComparer` - see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339118.aspx).

You can also use [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) instead - it is a data structure that does not allow duplicates (though with different references, you will still have this issue).

Comment: In this case that wouldn't help right?  (FileInfo is compared by reference, not value).

Comment: `HashSet<T>` is nice, as it does not throw an exception if the element is already present ... like that!

Comment: @JeffFoster i am shure that you can use a wrapper, enhance this wrapper with `IEquatable<T>`, override `.Equals` and `.GetHashCode` and `HashSet<T>` should work

Comment: @JeffFoster - quite right. Was already updating my answer to that effect.

Comment: for performance issue i would not use `List<T>`. why? in each iteration you do a `.Contains` or `.Any` (which lacks hash-based-comparison) - "best" case: each iteration adds an item... why not create a `Dictionary<string, FileInfo>`, where the key is an (invariant & case-ignore) representation of the eg `FullName` property. This will give you a performance boost, as `.ContainsKey` will do a hash-based-check (whilst the `List<T>`-solution lacks this kinda-check). Afterwards you just use the `.Values`-property...

Comment: Thanks, I believe this method may be beneficial for me to later as I will need a unique reference to allow the user to remove specific ToolStripMenuItem's that will be generated based on the list.

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair it is not necessary to use a wrapper; you can supply your own implementation of `IEqualityComparer<FileInfo>` that tests based on the full path.

Comment: @phoog ah, did not think of the other ctor ... thanks! anyway, i wouldn't use `HashSet<T>` nor `List<T>` for this ...

Answer (score 6):

Because the default `Object.Equals` implementation compares objects by reference, not by value. Each `FileInfo` instance you create is a different object, as far as .NET is concerned.

You can use LINQ to specify your custom comparison predicate in order to compare objects by different property:

```
if (dragDropFiles.Any(f => f.Name == file) == false)
{
    dragDropFiles.Add(fileInfo);
}
```

**[Edit]**

Since strings are compared by value, you might as well filter the list **before** you project it to `FileInfo`, like this:

```
private void OutputDragDrop(string[] files)
{
    dragDropFiles = files.Distinct().Select(f => new FileInfo(f)).ToList();
    debugList.DataSource = checkedDragDropFiles;
    debugList2.DataSource = dragDropFiles;
}
```

Comment: long time since i have seen `if (dragDropFiles.Any(f => f.Name == file) == false)` ... :) `if (!dragDropFiles.Any(f => f.Name == file))`

Comment: @Andreas: This is the way we did it in the old days. :-D Just kidding. Actually I only did it to emphasize that I inverted OP's logic (adding to list is now done inside the conditional).

Comment: :) well ... a `!` might easily be missed

Comment: Attention: this might work for this special case - but in other secenarios i would rather go for an invariant & case-ignore comparison. This can be easily done by passing `System.StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` or `System.StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` into `.Distinct`

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair: AFAIK, two filenames cannot sit in a same folder and differ only by casing, but if there is a potential that file names could get different casing, then I agree, it would be safer.

Comment: I believe that you can do this on *NIX systems - not shure though (as i am not a pengiun guy ...) ... besides that: that's why i've said "but in other scenarios"

Comment: Thanks for the reply but could you explain where the variable "f" comes from?
How is it being declared as the right type?

Comment: Edit: Ok, so on testing I discovered that this solution doesn't work. Although it doesn't display the duplicate items when I output the list to a listbox, it still actually adds the duplicate entry to my list.

I took a screenshot to demonstrate this:
http://i42.tinypic.com/5znrd.png
Program running:
http://i42.tinypic.com/xc7rpi.png

Comment: @negligible: do you clear the list before adding items (`dragDropFiles.Clear()`), if you are repeating this action? I don't see how it could add duplicates if it is initially empty. There could be a possibility that they had different casing, but they seem equal based on your screenshot. If you don't want to clear it, instead of `AddRange`, just change the entire list **(I've updated my answer)**.

Comment: @Groo: This is dynamically generating a context menu item for each list item. So if I cleared the dragDropFiles every time the user would have to drag them back into the application for them to appear on the menu again.

(I have long finished this actual project now)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create multiple FileInfo instances for the same file - so your list will contain every FileInfo only once, but it may have multiple FileInfos for the smae file.

So your best bet might be to use a Hashtable and use FileInfo.FullName as criterion.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an implementation of `ICollection<T>` that does not allow duplicates, whilst still retaining an ordering, consider using [`SortedSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070.aspx) rather than `List<T>`.